# Ubuntu 16.04 - unsupported php7.0-fpm

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, php, 16.10, php7

```
ubuntu-support-status --show-unsupported
```

Says that on my 16.04 and 16.10 installations php7.0-fpm, php7.0-intl, php7.0-mbstring, php7.0-mcrypt and couple more packages are unsupported. I've installed PHP from official repos, why this is showing as unsupported?

```
php -v
PHP 7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not supported *by Canonical*. They come from the Universe repository; support for those packages is provided by their developers.